# How to use AutoMapper for Sub-Objects in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I do have two classes:

```
public class Data
{
    public string? Property1 { get; set; }
    public string? Property2 { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; } = 1;
}

public class DataQuantity
{
    public Data Data { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Quantity { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

I want to use AutoMapper to map a "DataQuantity"-object to a "Data"-opject, where the Quantity from DataQuantity overwrites the Quantity from Data. If possible, I don't want to name all properties.

I've tried simple maps like:

```
CreateMap<DataQuantity, Data>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity));
```

In my service I call it like this:

```
var data = _mapper.Map<Data>(dataqty);
```

In "dataqty" all props are filled. After the mapping "data" props are all null or default.

dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5DZopv

Any help is welcome.

Comment: This should work out of the box without any explicit mapping. Can you please show the full [mre] representing the problem?

Comment: Which error or exception did you get?

Comment: "But this doesn't work." Means? When you say override you have given an existing Data instance to the call? Like `dest = mapper.Map(source, dest);`

Comment: I've extended my question with the call of the mapper.

Comment: please give us more information on how it doesn't work, what happens? 
but for now, on top of my mind, I can suggest you a very simple way to use an explicit operator or a simple static method in your DataQuantity to just convert to whatever type you want without using automapper but if you have to implement it only by automapper you should give us more information

Comment: I think I understand you, but you might need to create an extra MappingProfile class and then you can achieve this by creating a map between Data and Data and then use the AfterMap function to map the Quantity property. Can you managed it by yourself or you wanna help with that? Do you know how to create Mapper profiles?

Comment: I quickly created a dotnetfiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5DZopv

Comment: As you can see the Property1 was not mapped. My goal is that I don't need to name every property in the mapping profile as the "Data" class is the same in target and destination, but just nested.

Comment: Okay, now I understand more. I'll use your code on the fiddle, now what about this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/UbD4Lt

Comment: 1) You don't need to explicitly define `.ForMember` for each member, as long as they are the same type and name. 2) The mapper works with 1-to-1 mapping by checking type and name for each property. You are trying to map `Data Data` property to: nothing. The other side should have a Data property as well. Since you want to map `Data Data` property to 2 different properties, those are for which you need to explicitly define `.ForMember`.

Comment: I think something like: `cfg.CreateMap<DataQuantity, Data>().ForMember(dest => dest.Property1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Data.Property1)).ForMember(dest => dest.Property2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Data.Property2));`

Comment: Yeah Ergis is correct, I'm an idiot. It should be also like this: var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<DataQuantity, Data>()
        .ConvertUsing(src =>
        {
            var data = new Data
            {
                Property1 = src.Data.Property1,
                Property2 = src.Data.Property2,
                Quantity = src.Quantity
            };
            return data;
        });
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`IncludeMembers`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html#includemembers) to perform "customized" flattening:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Data, Data>();
cfg.CreateMap<DataQuantity, Data>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Data);
```

[Demo @dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jFE23S)

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know it could do flattening tbh. There, I learn something new today xD

Comment: @Ergis yes, AutoMapper supports flattening out of the box. Sometimes it is quite useful feature.

Comment: Thank you. That's the correct answer, as my goal was to not name all properties one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

The below is working, need to mention the Property explicitly.

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<DataQuantity, Data>().ForMember(dest => dest.Property1, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.Data.Property1));
});
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var dataqty = new DataQuantity { Data = new Data { Property1 = "prop1" }, Quantity = 3 };
var data = mapper.Map<Data>(dataqty);
Console.WriteLine("Mapped object:");
Console.WriteLine($"Property1: {data.Property1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Quantity: {data.Quantity}");
Console.ReadLine();
```